# GitKraken commit to github with userrname

Tags: git, github, commit, gitkraken

Recently switched to GitKraken and everything is great except that it commits to github not with my account username but with my real name. Wondering how to switch it to the username from github.
Here is a screenshot from when I used Github's client and GitKraken now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply go to GitKraken's Preferences->Git Config and change the `Name` field to your GitHub username.

[image]

Comment: No prob. Git actually doesn't care what name or email address you use. There is no authentication or requirement that you own the email address you're committing as, as long as you have the permissions to commit (it's your commit history after all)